# iPhone SDK 2d int array

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a 2d array in objective-c and I don't really want to use `NSArray` because I'm using int and the code would annoying: `{[array objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y]`, not to mention I would have to convert the numbers back from `NSNumber`... Seems like a lot of extra work.

Can't I do the following?

```
// .h file
int aTiles[10][2];

// .m file
aTiles = {
        { 0,  0}, // 0
        { 0,  1}, // 1
        { 1,  5}, // 2
        { 0,  0}, // 3
        { 0,  0}, // 4
        { 0,  0}, // 5
};
```

it works together in the same line (`int a[x][x] = {...};`), but I need the array to be public so I can access it from any function.

The second line says expecting semicolon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra comma near //5

Do you need to declare a type for aTiles?

```
 int aTiles = ...
```

Comment: Which is allowed to be there.

Comment: Jon Skeet gives a lovely explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason/7043410#7043410

Comment: Jon Skeet - is that the best you can do?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this has also been tagged C++, you can use an ivar:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > tiles;
```

Then you just resize and set initial element values in your object's initializer.

Otherwise, is this a global or an ivar? should it be const or mutable?

Comment: meh have no idea what that is lol. I dont think that xcode can use this. It supports C++, but not to that extent.

Comment: uhhh..... that's a typical 2D array in C++ - Xcode, GCC, and Clang all know what that is. If they could not support this, they just could not say they have modern C++ support :)

Answer (score 0):

I got slightly different errors when I tried your original code, but this worked:

```
// .h file
extern int aTiles[10][2];

// .m file
int aTiles[10][2] = {
        { 0,  0}, // 0
        { 0,  1}, // 1
        { 1,  5}, // 2
        { 0,  0}, // 3
        { 0,  0}, // 4
        { 0,  0}, // 5
};
```

Comment: It does work when you use extern, but when you try and use the array you get error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_aTiles", reference from: [LevelMaster loadLevel] in LevelMaster.o  note loadLevel is the function where i tried NSLog(@"test %i", aTiles[3][0]);

Comment: *when you use the array in another function you get that error, you can use it in the function you defined it in

Comment: Is LevelMaster in Objective-C or Objective-C++ (.m or .mm)?  What about the extern and declaration of aTiles?  Obj-C or Obj-C++?

Comment: They are objective-c, the xcode default, but you can use c/c++ methods i.e. int array[x][x].

Comment: I'd move to chat, but can't due to karma - What two files did you place my examples above in?  Based on your error, I'm assuming they are in something other than LevelMaster.h / LevelMaster.m?

Answer (score 0):

How about this awesomeness... (not really)

```
// .h
int aTiles[10][2];

// .m
int a[10][2] = {
        { 0,  0}, // 0
        { 0,  1}, // 1
        { 1,  5}, // 2
        { 0,  0}, // 3
        { 0,  0}, // 4
        { 0,  0}, // 5
};

for (int r = 0; r <= 5; r++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
      aTiles[r][c] = a[r][c];
   }
}
```

definitely a work around, but... cant figure out any other way. If anyone figures out the correct way, please let me know :P