# how is an "incomplete" initializer list parsed?

Tags: c++, c++11

By mistake I added an extra comma in a brace initialization list, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int myArray[10]{0,}; // how is this parsed?
}
```

I know very well what `myArray[10]{0}` does, however adding this extra comma shouldn't be parseable in my opinion. I don't think it is a comma operator, as I haven't seen any comma operator having "nothing" on its right hand side. So why does it compile successfully? (both on g++ and clang++)

Comment: Trailing comma in *braced-init-list* is ignored. See the grammar in **[dcl.init]/1**

Comment: FYI `int myArray[10]= {1,2,3,4,}; ` also compiles

Comment: @POW yes I know, I wonder why ;)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, this seem to be a very weird parsing scheme, I see no reason why is not just an error but just because the standard says so.

Comment: @vsoftco: It's for making code-generation easier. Whatever you might think of that.

Comment: @vsoftco See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7043372/1870232)

Comment: @POW, thanks, now I see I'm not the first one to have asked this question, although I didn't find the link before. The code generation "explanation" is a bit sketchy imo, but yes, it is an explanation.