# What are the downsides of optional trailing commas?

Tags: parsing, grammar

Many languages have several rules like the following in their grammars, which forbid trailing commas:

```
call-expr: ident '(' expr-list? ')';
expr-list: expr | expr-list ',' expr;
```

However, the following formulation allows (but does not require) trailing commas, which has [well-known advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason):

```
call-expr: ident '(' expr-list? expr? ')';
expr-list: expr ',' | expr-list expr ',';
```

Is there any *downside* to always using this, at least internally?

Comment: Perl allows trailing commas.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that many languages *do* allow it.

Comment: It's not something you'd likely know if you don't know that language.

Comment: The downside is the possiblity that an amateur, entering a list of data, might leave a bit of data out without it being detected.  I think optional trailing commas is an assumption the language users are expert, and your are trying to make their life easier.   So whether it is a downside depends on who you think the typical user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside is ambiguity where empty entries are permitted. Consider the following arrays in Javascript:

- `[1,,3]`
- `[1,,3,]`

Are they identical? Is their length identical? Should it be? (Answer: yes, but not in IE<=7)

Answer (score 1):

Languages which allow procedure parameters to be left off (I'm particularly thinking of the old HP systems language SPL; there may be others) would fail on this because the compiler would assume that there was a skipped parameter after the trailing comma which the procedure does not call for. I'll grant that this is a minor disadvantage - on the other hand, IMO the stated benefits are equally minor.