# What is the difference between const char* testarr[]={{},}; and const char* testarr[]={{}};

Tags: c++, gcc

1. `const char*  testarr[]={{},};`
2. `const char*  testarr[]={{}};`

Both of these statements are compiled and works well (during a test code). But I do not understand why the first statement (with a comma - , ) succeeded.
Any thoughts or comments?

To my senses - the unnecessary comma should cause it to fail.
Environment : Linux, g++, and this is in global area of a header file.

Comment: Are you using c or c++? They are different languages and might have different answers

Comment: Disregarding the fact that empty arrays are not legal in standard C, no difference. The trailing comma in an initializer list is ignored.

Comment: [Why is a trailing comma in an initializer-list allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-why-is-a-trailing-comma-in-an-initializer-list-allowed)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think they both have a single element (at least in c++ https://godbolt.org/z/rM1zeGEc9)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles As I said - in standard C they are not allowed. Different extensions may implement it differently. I suspect the same is true for C++, but not an expert in it.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention : In my case , it is global.

Comment: gcc certainly complains about the code in c mode: https://godbolt.org/z/asn9hrsWx

Comment: @AlanBirtles It complains about other things though.. Here is simplified test for both C and C++ with `pedantic` warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/azYnsz6cq , https://godbolt.org/z/sP13hzEbb - both are complaining about array of zero size.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's different code in c++ though, the original code is a perfectly valid way of creating an array containing a single null pointer