# Binary search array showing -1 as result

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search

```
#include<stdio.h>
int binary_search(int arr[], int size ,int element){
    int low, mid, high; 
    low=0;
    high=size-1;
    //start of search
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == element){
        return mid;
        }
        if(arr[mid]<element){
        low= mid+1;
        }
        else{
        high = mid-1;
        }
    }
    //end of search
    return -1;
}
int main(){
    int arr[20]={1,20,31,44,54,68,70,85};
    int size= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int element=44;
    int Si= binary_search(arr,size,element);
    printf("Element was found at index: %d \n",Si);
    return 0;

}
```

why does my code returns -1 everytime .
I tried changing arr[20] to arr[] in main function and it started working fine.
Can someone explain me the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code creates an integer array of length `20`, [with all the elements after `85` being initialized to zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414785/12122460).

```c
int arr[20]={1,20,31,44,54,68,70,85};
```

The [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) gives the size, in bytes, of the integer array `arr` of length 20, which causes the value of `size` to be 20. This causes the binary search algorithm to fail, as it does not deal with arrays that are not sorted.